# Remove notification on fragment's onStop()

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

So I have an ongoing notification that I only want to remove when the application is closed. I removed the notification on OnDestroy when I used it in an activity. Now I want to use it in a fragment, but since the onDestroy method is not always called I remove it on onStop. When I press the home button, the notification disappears. How can I do this? (I also tried onDestroyView and that doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> application is closed

there's no concept of closing application really on Android.

> but since the onDestroy method is not always called

That's actually fine. Putting app in background is not equivalent of killing it. There may be no need from system perspective to get your code killed/garbage collected.

> Also removing notifications when user puts your app in background pretty much indicates these notifications are useless from user perspective.
>
> onDestroy method is not always called I remove it on onStop

It indicates your notifications are tightly coupled with Fragments. That's sounds bad idea. I'd rather delegate notification handling out of the Fragment and then manage its visibility (if that really makes any sense to do) in code triggered i.e. via code utilizing [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) or recent [Lifecycle-aware Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle).